# What is the authentic Nishpatthi (Etymology) of Samadhi?

Tags: vedanta, yoga, sanskrit, etymology, samadhi

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samadhi),

Various interpretations for the term's etymology are possible:

> - *sam,* "together"; a, "toward"; stem of *dadhati,* "puts, places": "a putting or joining together;"
> - *sam,* "together" or "integrated"; *ā,* "towards"; *dhā,* "to get, to hold": "to acquire integration or wholeness, or truth" (*samāpatti*);
> - *sam,* "uniformly" or "fully"; *adhi,* "to get established: : a state    wherein one establishes himself to the fullest extent in the Supreme Consciousness;
> - *samā,* "even"; *dhi,* "intellect": a state of total equilibrium of a detached intellect.
> - *sam,* "perfect," "complete." *dhi,* "consciousness": a state of being where "all distinctions between the person who is the subjective meditator, the act of meditation and the object of meditation merge into oneness."
> - *sama,* "equanimous" *dhi,* "*buddhi* or the intellect"

**Can someone please give actual Nishpatthi and Pada Vibhaga for the word and also cite authentic sources?**

Comment: @Archit no no this Vedantic question in the cateogory of Nirukta of Vedanga.

Answer (score 1):

The sanskrit dictionary Vacaspatyam defines samādhi as:

*samādhi* pu° sam + ā + dhā--ki . 1 samādhāyāṃ dhyeyavastuni ekāgratayā
manasaḥsthāpanarūpe 2 dhyānabhede 2 vacanābhāve 4 niyame ca amaraḥ .

1. samādhāyām dhyeyavastuni ekāgratavā manasaḥsthāpanarūpe - fixing the mind intensely on the object of meditation
2. dhyānabhede - as something distinct from dhyāna - Monier willaims: with Buddhists Samādhi is the fourth and last stage of Dhyāna or intense abstract meditation [ MWB. 209 ]
3. vacanābhāve - as something in which there is lack of any speaking/utterance
4. niyame - as something in which there is restriction (of senses)